# NHibernate refuses to validate character varying for varchar(255) in postgres12

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, nhibernate, orm

I've setup a little project for me to tinker around with NHibernate. I'm using a pgsql 12 server with Npgsql-Driver.

Some of my properties are strings and I defined them in their map like this (Mapping By Code)

```cs
property(i => i.Name, m =>
            {
                m.Column("name");
                m.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);
            });
```

But for all my string properties it get

> Wrong column type in postgres.public.instances for column name. Found: character varying, Expected varchar(255)

Is this a misconfiguration by me, or are some type/keyword mappings missing in NHibernate/Driver?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use NHibernateUtil.StringClob instead. That one maps to pgsql type text under the hood which actually has close to no performance hit and some advantages when used in functions.